Flutter new 3.24.1 and Dart 3.5 update issue Gradle build failed: Could not find com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.20
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.20.
     Searched in the following locations:
   Required by:
         project :app > project :flutter_logs
not slove
BUILD FAILED in 13m 17s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Why this error?
I expected the build to complete successfully without any dependency resolution errors.

implementation 'com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.20 is deprecated
Visit JitPack and search for umair13adil/RxLogs
then use your preferable version.
for my case,
this solved by implementing app/build.gradle
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:v1.0.20'
}

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
if its not work then for windows press ctrl+shift+f and mac cmd+shift+f search RxLogs:1.0.20 and replace RxLogs:v1.0.20..then run your app.thank you
